# Notepad++ exclude starts with a two digit number

Tags: notepad++, regex

I would like to exclude anything that starts with `87`. By combining the first two digits, I can find lines that start with `^8+7` or `^87`.  But I was trying to use `^[^8+7]`, but it doesn't seem to work. I can't find an example where it excludes the lines by looking at anything that starts with two digit numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using negative lookahead. I don't have Notepad++ on this computer, so I can't say for sure if it supports this kind of regular expression. Give it a try.

```
^(?!87).*$
```

This basically matches any line that does not start with `87`.

More information: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: It works perfectly.  Thank you for the link as well.